# Set up for Multiple IP to single DNS

Tags: nginx, server, dns, ip, infrastructure

I have installed nginx load balancer on two server . I  want to assign one same DNS for both IP of server! 
So that I can use assign DNS for hitting request which will route request on both nginx server simultaneously!!
Thanks on advance !! 
I wanted do it virtually...not through fqdn.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I need to assign one DNS to both IP ...how to assign it??

Comment: Great question!  Follow the regular procedure to assign a single IP to a non-FQDN, then repeat once!

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed nginx load balancer on two server . I want to assign one same DNS for both IP of server! So that I can use assign DNS for hitting request which will route request on both nginx server simultaneously!! Thanks on advance !! I wanted do it virtually...not through fqdn.

Follow the normal procedure to assign a single IP address to a DNS name.

Repeat once, for the other IP address.

Good luck!